# Работает только посадочная страница без подгруженных стилей. Ошибка 404 при переходе с посадочной. Symfony

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony3

Здравствуйте борюсь с ошибкой битый день.
Залил сайт по ftp на хостинг Reg.ru. Провел все операции рекомендуемые [Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html) через консоль по ssh. 
Routing происходит через аннотации.

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('homepage/index.html.twig');
}
```

Ссылки на файлы через asset()

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/homepage/main.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('js/slider/style.css') }}" />
```

Файл .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Сам [сайт](http://www.boldast.ru)

Answer (score 0):

Выполните эти команды

```
1. php app\console assets:install
2. php app\console assetic:dump
3. php app\console cache:clear --env=prod
4. php app\console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59807/discussion-on-answer-by-------).